# Blender: Make seams and UV mapping not working

Tags: uv

Im extremely confused as to what is going on with my file and why the seams and uv mapping are not working. can someone help me?

https://youtu.be/DB40DHK7bSU

Comment: Can you upload the blend file so I can take a look at it?

Comment: One thing I just noticed is that your mesh has a mirror modifier but is still a full mesh. You may want to delete one half of the mesh. That could be the issue.